# Указать тип переменной в виде унаследованных классов. Python typing

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

У меня есть

```
class A:
    pass
```

И есть классы

```
class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass
```

И я хочу объявить возвращаемый тип у функции - экземпляр класса, который унаследовался у `A`, то есть это `B` и `C`, как это сделать верно? Есть вариант с `Union[B, C]`, но перечислять все классы - не особо хороший вариант потому что это:

1. Долго
2. Придется менять все время списки в функциях если будут изменения, а делать свой тип для объединения не хочется.

Есть ли какие-то другие варианты?

```
def foo(a: str, b: str) -> ?:
    ...
```

Comment: А как та функция выглядит? Эта функция одна и та же для классов, но у нее разный возвращаемый тип?

Comment: @gil9red, функция может выглядить как-угодно, но суть в том, что она возвращает любой экземпляр класса с базовым в виде `A`. Например, нужно вернуть разные записи из БД, которые унаследовались от базовой модели

Comment: @Интик, вы меня удивили. Базовый пример: класс Человек, поля: пол, имя. Класс Ученик, унаследовались от Человека. Поля: поля человека + школа. Теперь спроецируйте это на БД. Вообще это просто пример, к нему не нужно привязываться так сильно :)

Comment: Насчет `Union[B, C, ...]` если у вас везде один и тот же `Union`, то объявите его типа: `FOO = Union[B, C, ...]` и подставляйте `FOO` в качестве типа. Насчет той функции непонятно... у вас она как какая-то фабрика работает? Она по каким-то аргументам или признакам возвращает разные типы объектов?

Comment: @gil9red, и фабрики бывают, и другие примеры. Просто я все время не знал, как объявить, нигде не нашел, и вот решил спросить здесь. Объявить через свой тип - единственный пока рабочий вариант, но выглядит "не по-питоновски", и вот я интересуюсь, есть ли еще какие-нибудь варианты

Comment: Не соглашусь насчет "питоновски", создание своего типа описано в спецификации: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases

Comment: @gil9red, как раз именно по-этому я это использую, но тут проблема в том, что создание своего типа обязывает все время редактировать список по мере изменения, а все эти классы можно объединить по признаку, что в базовых классах есть `A`, это не должно быть, как мне кажется, таким сложным. Такими темпами, походу, придется предложить изменения в интерпретатор :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, вам нужно использовать [typing.Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type).

Пример из спеки:

```
class User: ...
class BasicUser(User): ...
class ProUser(User): ...
class TeamUser(User): ...

# Accepts User, BasicUser, ProUser, TeamUser, ...
def make_new_user(user_class: Type[User]) -> User:
    # ...
    return user_class()
```